# Esper left outer join with subquery

Tags: java, left-join, esper

I'm trying to apply in essper this query:

```
select a.partA, b.partB, b.count from call.win:time_batch(_WINDOW_) as a
left outer join (select count(*) count, partA from 
call.win:time_batch(_WINDOW_) group by partA ) b on a.partA = b.partA
```

but I got exception

> Caused by: com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near '(' ('select' is a reserved keyword) at line 1 column 96, please check the outer join within the from clause near reserved keyword 'select' [select a.partA, b.partB, b.count from call.win:time_batch(*WINDOW*) as a left outer join(select count(*) count, partA from call.win:time_batch(*WINDOW*) group by partA ) b on a.partA = b.partA]

call is my eventTypeName

Comment: It seems that the query tries to accomplish just this: select partA, partB, count(*) from call.win:time_batch(_WINDOW_) group by partA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no support for subqueries in the from-clause in Esper as of version 5.4.